# how to get latest messages from all users

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables one is for users and other is for messages i want the latest messages of every user who sent the message to user 1 my code is below

```
SELECT u.profile_pic
     , u.username
     , u.firstname
     , u.lastname
     , m.message_from
     , m.message_body 
  FROM user u
  JOIN messages m
    ON m.message_from = u.user_no 
 WHERE m.message_to = $userno
 ORDER 
    BY m.sent_time DESC
```

Comment: and latest messages stands for how many?

Comment: each user 1 latest message to '$userno'

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to give you an answer if you could include your table structures (is there a unique id on the `messages` table?). But from the information in your question, this should work:

```
SELECT 
  u.profile_pic,
  u.username,
  u.firstname,
  u.llastname,
  m.message_from,
  m2.message_body 
FROM  user u
JOIN (SELECT message_from,message_to,max(sent_time)
      FROM  messages
      GROUP BY message_from,message_to) m 
        ON user.user_no = messages.message_from 
        AND messages.message_to = '$userno'
JOIN messages m2 ON m.message_from = m2.message_from
                 AND m.message_to = m2.message_to
                 AND m.sent_time = m2.sent_time
```

Basically, the subselect will pull out all of the latest messages from one user to another, which you then join against to filter out all the others.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to message table on same user and newer sent_time. The latest of each user is the one that doesn't have such message:

```
SELECT profile_pic,username,firstname,lastname,messages.message_from,messages.message_body 
FROM  user 
JOIN messages ON user.user_no = messages.message_from 
LEFT JOIN messages AS newermessages ON user.user_no = newermessages.message_from AND messages.sent_time < newermessages.sent_time
WHERE  messages.message_to = '$userno' 
AND newermessages.id IS NULL
ORDER BY messages.sent_time DESC
```

Comment: i write your query but getting an error-Column 'message_from' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: I forgot you have to use table alias on all messages columns now, updated answer.

Comment: I also assumed you have `messages.id` column, if not, change it.

Answer (score 0):

The latest message from each user:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM messages a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT message_from
            , MAX(sent_time) max_sent_time 
         FROM messages 
        GROUP 
           BY message_from
     ) b
    ON b.message_from = a.message_from
   AND b.max_sent_time = a.sent_time;
```

The remainder of this problem has been left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding the field of the ORDER BY clause into your selection:

```
SELECT u.profile_pic
     , u.username
     , u.firstname
     , u.lastname
     , m.message_from
     , m.message_body 
     , m.sent_time
  FROM user u
  JOIN messages m
    ON m.message_from = u.user_no 
 WHERE m.message_to = $userno
 ORDER 
    BY m.sent_time DESC
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to write desc in question now again look at my question and now give me the answer

Comment: @user3610919 _and now give me the answer_ ? Dance for me monkey-boy? I hope this is some language-type mishap? You probably need the order-by-field in the selection...